# ReportService2010 - Can I extract ValidValues property when it's query based?

Tags: c#, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am trying to pull report parameters from the report server using ReportService2010 proxy, but I noticed ValidValue[] array from the returned ItemParameter[] array comes as null if the values are query-based.

Is there a way to return them directly or do I have to use the query used for retrieving the parameter values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This link has the information you need:

[Using GetReportParameters in Reporting Services](http://odetocode.com/articles/123.aspx)

In short, the first thing you must do is set the `forRendering` parameter to true when calling to `GetItemParameters`.

If you have parameters with valid values from a query that uses other parameters, then you may need to call `GetItemParameters` several times until all dependencies are resolved. See the link for the complete explanation.